# Is DatatypeConverter thread-safe?

Tags: java, thread-safety, base64, jaxp

In particular, is the method `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(String)` thread-safe?

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing in the documentation that suggests the class is thread-safe. Therefore I recommend you assume it isn't.

I'd recommend [`Base64`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/archives/1.9/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) from Apache Commons Codec which states it's thread-safe in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

My reading of the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api/2.2.11/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.java#DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary%28java.lang.String%29) is that *that* implementation is thread-safe.

- The `parseBase64Binary` method calls a `parseBase64Binary` method on a shared `DatatypeConverterImpl` object that is lazily created.
- It is easy to see that the lazy creation is thread safe.  (The code is in another Answer ...)
- An examination of `DatatypeConverterImpl` shows that it has no instance variables, so there *cannot* be thread-safety concerns over access / update to the state of the instance.
- The `DatatypeConverterImpl.parseBase64Binary` method (in turn) calls the `static` `_parseBase64Binary` method.
- The `_parseBase64Binary` method uses its input (which is immutable) and local variables that refer to thread-confined objects.  The only exception is the `decodeMap` variable which is a `private static final` array.
- The `decodeMap` variable is initialized and safely published during class (static) initialization.
- Once initialized, the `decodeMap` variable is only ever read.  Thus, there can be no synchronization issues or memory model "hazards" related to updates.

Of course, this analysis only applies to the version of the class that I linked to.  It is conceivable that the method is not thread-safe in other versions.  (But the source code is freely available for multiple versions, so you should be able to check this for the version of JAXP that you are using.)

Comment: Thank you. I can't understand why this class doesn't let you build a separate instance to avoid this kind of problems...

Comment: Well ... presumably ... because there is no problem to avoid.  But by that logic, they should *specify* that the method is thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

After taking a look at the `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(String)` source code ([JAXB api](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api/2.2.11/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.java#DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary%28java.lang.String%29)) which is a static method using an immutable class as an argument.

```
final public class DatatypeConverter {
    ...
    // delegate to this instance of DatatypeConverter
    private static volatile DatatypeConverterInterface theConverter = null;

    ...

    public static byte[] parseBase64Binary( String lexicalXSDBase64Binary ) {
        if (theConverter == null) initConverter();
        return theConverter.parseBase64Binary( lexicalXSDBase64Binary );
    }

    ...

    private static synchronized void initConverter() {
        theConverter = new DatatypeConverterImpl();
    }

    ...
}
```

We can assume that it's thread safe. The initConverter() method is static synchronized.

Comment: Yes, but what about the `theConverter.parseBase64Binary(...)`??

Comment: theConverter instance is volatile if you looked at the source code

Comment: Ok, but we can still have problems...taken from the Java Concurrency Tutorial:

"Atomic actions cannot be interleaved, so they can be used without fear of thread interference. However, this does not eliminate all need to synchronize atomic actions, because memory consistency errors are still possible."